# How to update a table column with a loop of specific numbers that fills entire column

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Kind of hard to explain so i will show an example.

Let's say i have the numbers 3, 4, 12, and 19. I would like to add them to my customer table like this:

```
Customer Column    Other Column
ralph              3  
higgons            4
johnny             12
sarah              19
randy              3
jack               4
pete               12
harry              19
goose              3
```

And keep adding them like this for the entire table until the entire Other Column is filled. Is this possible? And how would i go about doing this? I assumed arrays but i'm probably wrong. Would appreciate any and all suggestions. I'm not even sure how to word this question so 2 hours of googling has gotten me no where. If you would like any additional info i'd be more than happy to share. Using Access 2010 if it matters.

Comment: You can use CURSOR for that. for SQL : [see this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) or you have to use `for loop` in code side..

Answer (score 0):

I have a kinda lame solution.

```
OleDbCommand datacommand = new OleDbCommand();
datacommand.Connection = dataConnection;
int[] numArray = new int[]; 
//Fill the array
for (int i=0; i<numArray.Length; i++)
{
    datacommand.CommandText = "UPDATE tblCostumers \n" +
                              "SET  Other  =   " + numArray[i] + "     \n" +
                              "WHERE  RowNum = " + i;
    OleDbDataReader dataReader = datacommand.ExecuteReader();
}
```

kinda new to this, so this is probably not the best solution available.

Comment: that code looks good. So how do i implement it into my form query?

Comment: thnks for the help, i'm gonna look into it more when i'm sober an post the results. Do i just make this code in VBA and call it in access?

Comment: donnu about VB. this is C# code. It is using "system.Data.OleDb. You might want to elaborate on the way you access your database.